# Eclipse not updating dependency JARs in web deployment

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse, I have a project, say ProjectA, which is a dynamic web module. ProjectB is a library used by ProjectA. I have added ProjectB to ProjectA's web deployment assembly, with the deploy path `/WEB-INF/lib/ProjectB.jar`.

When I deploy ProjectA onto a Tomcat v6.0 server, everything works fine. However, if I make any changes to ProjectB, no matter what I do, these changes don't seem to be picked up by the deployment.

I have tried the following options *Project->Clean...* from the main menu, and *Clean Module Work Directory...* from the server's context menu, but neither works. The only thing that seems to work is deleting the Project, then re-importing it into Eclipse.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Check out JRebel http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/

Comment: I have exactly the same problem now. Did you ever figure out what caused the dependent project to stop building when deploying the main project? I have a Dynamic Web Project which has another project on the build path from the same workspace. It is exported and the deployment assembly is still set correctly. This project has deployed fine many times before but now the changes made to the dependent project are not triggering the jar to be rebuilt when deploying...Clean doesn't help.

Comment: I removed the project dependency completely, cleaned, then added it again, clean and run on server and it updated correctly. I can only conclude that something got corrupted in Eclipse. I've now added a version number to the dependent project so that I can check after building that that jar was also built. Only other option is to manually export the dependent project each time, but that is a little inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that Eclipse recognizes ProjectB.jar as a dependency from Project->Properties->Java Build Path? In general, it should show up there. I'm not sure about your exact situation though.

Comment: Yes, ProjectB is included in the build path of ProjectA.

Answer (score 0):

You could check that ProjectB has to be exported as a dependency to ProjectA (Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export). This may solve your problem. But since I usually work with an EAR file myself, I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Is ProjectB exported as part of ProjectA? or does ProjectA refer to ProjectB externally? Seems like you want ProjectB to be part of ProjectA:

```
Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export
```

(make sure ProjectB is exported).

If you use ant build or some other builder, make sure those projects are exported too in the build process as oppose to you manually copy pasting ProjectB into ProjectA's WEB-INF folder.

Also, did you check the "Build Automatically" ? That make sure all projects and any project dependent on them will be re-built.